# Android: Why my icon does not appear in the Action Bar?

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest

Please,
See my picture.

Why the app icon is not on the top left corner????

Thanks!!

[image]

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.enma"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="PickerActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.enma.flatdesign3.MainActivity2"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my icon:

[image]

Comment: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: That's not an `ActionBar`. :-)

Longer answer: That's not an `ActionBar`, that's just the titlebar. Use the following attribute on your `<application>` tag to trigger the `ActionBar`:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Comment: thanks, but in my understanding the ActionBar is always present,and I do not have to use a theme to invoke it.... am I right??? or not.... :-/ Thank you very much - LISA

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think that specifically is related to the `android:targetSdkVersion` that you set. Try setting it higher than 8 (2.2), preferably 17 (4.2.2) for it to show itself. :-) @LisaAnne

Comment: putting  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" /> changed nothing :-(

Comment: Try putting: `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" />` instead. @LisaAnne

Comment: added android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"